# CSS Grid not showing columns as expected

Tags: html, css

My intent is to create a three column grid, and have the two elements below show side-by-side. I have the following HTML file:

```css
.main-grid {
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.main-col {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.right-box {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="main-col">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right-box">
    <p>Test 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My understanding of the grid system is that this should display `Test` roughly in the middle, and `Test 2` to the right of it, but they both display below each other.

Comment: You didn't apply `display: grid;`

Comment: Nowhere do you apply display grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `display` property with value `grid`, before css knows it should treat it as a grid:

```css
.main-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    display:grid
  }

  .main-col {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    border: 2px solid red;

  }
  
  .right-box {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
```